# Exponential Smoothing in a time series Sarima model forecast

Tags: time-series, smoothing, exponential, model-fitting, sarimax

I'm making a time series forecast using SARIMA and for that I've made the series stationary and applied exponential smoothing to it, so that I could get a better fit and a more clear seasonality.

However, I'm not finding a way to undo the exponential smoothing, so I could reverse the SARIMA Model back to the original scale in a way that I could plot it and compare to the original df. I was able to get a forecast in the original scale, but I have no way of seeing how accurate that is. How can I do this so I evaluate my fit through the plot?